# What is a good way test the lftp xfer:timeout feature

Tags: timeout, lftp

Has anyone who has experience with the lftp utility been able to test the xfer:timeout feature?
I am switching to lftp client version 4.8.3 and need a way to test xfer:timeout.

xfer:timeout (time interval)
maximum  time  without  any transfer progress.
It can be used to limit maximum time to retry
a transfer from a server not supporting transfer restart.

Comment: Start a long tranfer, and, on the server, `sudo kill -STOP` the serving process to get your timeout. Read `man 7 signal; man kill`.